# Is there a way to render content onto an XGraphics and then use the XGraphics to render it again on different pages of the PDF?

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

As the title says, I've drawn some text onto an `PdfSharp.Drawing.XGraphics` object. Is it possible to put that text onto another part of the PDF without having to draw it all again? The underlying `System.Drawing.Graphic` method `AddMetafileComment` implies there might be a metafile somewhere buried below the surface. But I can't see a way to access it. Does `XGraphics.CreateMeasureContext` help at all?

I'm using PdfSharp-gdi.1.50.5147.0.

Answer (score 0):

`XGraphics` objects execute the drawing instructions directly. There is no "macro recorder" and AFAIK metafiles are not supported.

With PDFsharp, you can create an `XForm` object and draw that on multiple PDF pages.
https://pdfsharp.net/wiki/XForms-sample.ashx